# sending email using django template engine

Tags: django, django-templates

I am using django's template engine to render my email templates.

I have no `RequestContext` when rendering my email, there for I have no access to my `STATIC_URL` and cant use the `{% url %}` template tag.

How can I make it work while I am not generating the email from a view function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add domain/url you may get it from Site model:

```
message_data.update({'site': Site.objects.get_current()})
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you think you need RequestContext for the `{% url %}` tag. It's a normal tag, you can use it in any template.

And STATIC_URL is just a setting: if you can't get it from the context processor, just pass it in manually into the template context: `context['STATIC_URL'] = settings.STATIC_URL`, or even use the [`{% static %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static) template tag.

Comment: I need to re-write my question.. because now I understand my problem better. the whole problem relates to the fact that (% url %) does not addup the site-url so I recieve /url instead of http://domain/url. I assume I just need to add the url name.